# How to add/remove element in list on the basis of selection of 2 dropdown list in multi select bootstrap dropdown jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, bootstrap-multiselect

Hope all of you fine and doing well.

I am using multi select bootstrap drop down jquery. I am using asp.net core to populdate Listbox, its working fine for selection,select all etc.

But i want that  when i select element from `Dropdown A` then this element must be removed from `dropdown B` and if i unselect element from dropdown A then it must added/show in dropdownB. And vice virsa as well, if element selected in dropdown B then this element removed from dropdownA, also if select all from dropdownA then all elements removed from dropdownB and vice virsa as well.
Hope you understand guys.

For example: If A,B,C,D values in dropdownlistA and if i select A then it must be disable or hide from dropdownB,if i select all then must remove all from dropdownB, and also vice virsa for dropdownB as well,
`Note: DropdownA and DropdownB both have same number of values/elements,same text ,same value,`

View

```
@section AddToHead{
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css1/bootstrap-3.1.1.min.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css1/bootstrap-multiselect.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/js1/bootstrap-2.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/js1/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
}
<form class="column" asp-controller="group"  asp-action="createresult" style="height:100%;" method="post">
  <span class="column" style="height:50px;">
        @Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.AvailablePlayers, Model.AvailablePlayers, new { id = "PlayersTeamA", onChange = "getSelectedOptions(this)", multiple = "multiple" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TeamOnePlayers)

    </span>
     <span class="column">
        @Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.AvailablePlayers, Model.AvailablePlayers, new { id = "PlayersTeamB", onChange = "getSelectedOptions(this)", multiple = "multiple" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TeamTwoPlayers)

    </span>

   </form>

    </div>
        @section Scripts {



<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#PlayersTeamA').multiselect({
            includeSelectAllOption: true
        });
        $('#PlayersTeamB').multiselect({
            includeSelectAllOption: true
        });

      
    });

    function getSelectedOptions(sel) {
        var idddl = sel.id;
       
        var opts = [],
            opt;
        var len = sel.options.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            opt = sel.options[i];

            if (opt.selected) {
                opts.push(opt);
                var idul = sel.id;
                alert(idul);
                var ul = document.getElementById(idul);
                ul.removeChild(ul.childNodes[1]);



               
              

            }
        }

        return opts;
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't be easiest way to do it by "just disabling" option in the other select instead?

Comment: yeah please provide me disabling is fine for me, i also try with get dropdown by id and remove child, but its not working, i see console debugger apply on code and look like <ul> have no id , its just class ,when its convert into multi select dropdown bootstrap. i stuck with this issue about 2 days but not able to resolve this issue :( please help me sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working demo like below:

```
@model Players
<form class="column" asp-controller="group" asp-action="createresult" style="height:100%;" method="post">
<div id="A">
    <span class="column" style="height:50px;">
        @Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.AvailablePlayers, Model.AvailablePlayers, new { id = "PlayersTeamA", multiple = "multiple" })
    </span>
</div>  
<div id="B">
    <span class="column">
        @Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.AvailablePlayers, Model.AvailablePlayers, new { id = "PlayersTeamB", multiple = "multiple" })
    </span>
</div>
</form>

@section Scripts {
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.15/js/bootstrap-multiselect.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.15/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css"/>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('#PlayersTeamA').multiselect({
                includeSelectAllOption: true   
            });
            $('#PlayersTeamB').multiselect({
                includeSelectAllOption: true
            });
        });

        var data = [];
        $('#B option').each(function (index, item) {
            data.push({ label: this.label, value: this.value });
        });

        $("#PlayersTeamA").change(function () {
            var selectedText = $('#PlayersTeamA').val();
            var newData = data;

            selectedText.forEach(function (element, index, array) {
                newData = newData.filter(function (el) { return el.value != element; });
            });           
            $("#PlayersTeamB").multiselect('dataprovider', newData);
        });
    </script>
}
```

My testing model:

```
public class Players
{
    public SelectList AvailablePlayers { get; set; }
}
public class AvailablePlayer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My testing controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var player = new List<AvailablePlayer>()
    {
        new AvailablePlayer(){ Id=1,Name="aa"},
        new AvailablePlayer(){ Id=2,Name="bb"},
        new AvailablePlayer(){ Id=3,Name="cc"}
    };
    var model = new Players()
    {
        AvailablePlayers = new SelectList(player, "Id", "Name")
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are using bootstrap's multiselect. In the documentation, we can see that you can configure data as follows (after executing .multiselect on particular input, as you do in your sample):

```
var data = [
    {label: "Messi", value: "Messi"},
    {label: "Ronaldo", value: "Ronaldo"}
];
$("#PlayersTeamA").multiselect('dataprovider', data);
```

Now, attach to 'onchange' event of #PlayersTeamA and update the available data for #PlayersTeamB, for example like this:

```
$("#PlayersTeamA").change(function () {
        var selectedText = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
        var newData = data.filter(function(el) { return el.value == selectedText; });
        $("#PlayersTeamB").multiselect('dataprovider', newData);
});
```

You have to attach to onchange of #PlayersTeamB as well, I believe (so that it works in both directions).